# Trying to program a code that outputs even numbers in C

Tags: c

What is my error here? My code SHOULD, get the value of stop, then while x is less than or equal to stop (y), it should run the while loop. Which basically prints x if it's even and continues the loop if it's odd.

```
int main(void){

int x = 1;
int y;


printf("What number should I count to?: ");
scanf(" %d", y);

while(x<=y){

    if(x % 2 != 0){
        x++;
        continue;
    }
    printf(" %d, ", x);
}


return 0;}
```

Comment: 90% of beginner questions about C programming would be avoided if people would use `-Wall -Werror` with GCC.

Comment: One important part of debugging is *verifying* that your assumptions are actually true.  In this case, you could print the value of `y` to verify that its value is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Not using GCC @JonathonReinhart

Comment: @ming Then enable the warnings in your compiler and pay attention to them. If your compiler can't detect that you're passing an integer where a pointer is required, then I suggest you get a new compiler.

Answer (score 2):

As everyone else has pointed out, your `scanf` call is incorrect and should use `&y` like

```
scanf("%d", &y);
```

However, what no one else has noted is you can improve your loop efficiency signficantly. Instead of testing for even *inside* the loop, I would do so once before the loop and increment the initial value if it is odd (forcing an even initial condition). Then you can increment by two inside the loop without testing again. Like,

```
if (x % 2 != 0) {
    x++;
}
while (x <= y) {
    printf("%d, ", x);
    x += 2;
}
```

Comment: You can add little more efficiency in OP's code by initializing `x` with `2` instead of `1` and remove this `if` block `if (x % 2 != 0) {...` altogether.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

You need `&y` in your `scanf` as `scanf` needs a *pointer* to `y`. Otherwise, you'll get a segfault.

Also, you're only incrementing `x` for odd numbers, so you'll get stuck in an infinite loop because once you hit an even number, you never increment `x` again.

Here's the cleaned up code [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
    int x = 1;
    int y;

    printf("What number should I count to?: ");
    scanf(" %d", &y);

    for (;  x <= y;  ++x) {
        if ((x % 2) != 0)
            continue;
        printf(" %d, ", x);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> I've never seen a for loop with the first part empty before, what does that imply?

Loosely, `for` loops have the general form:

```
for (initialization_expr;  condition_expr;  iteration_expr)
```

Any or all of these sub-expressions may be eliminated (i.e. blank).

For example, we could replace:

```
while (1)
```

With:

```
for (;;)
```

Personally, I prefer the `while`, but some people use the `for` as a "forever" loop [they both are just as fast].

Basically, we can omit any of them we wish. Here's a forever loop that increments `x` on each iteration:

```
for (x = 1;  ;  ++x)
```

Suppose we change your program so that we first output even numbers, but we then add a loop that outputs odd numbers that *start* where the even numbers left off:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
    int x = 1;
    int y;

    printf("What number should I count to?: ");
    scanf(" %d", &y);

    // output even numbers
    printf("Even:");
    for (;  x <= y;  ++x) {
        if ((x % 2) != 0)
            continue;
        printf(" %d, ", x);
    }
    printf("\n");

    // increase limit
    y *= 2;

    // output odd numbers
    printf("Odd:");
    for (;  x <= y;  ++x) {
        if ((x % 2) == 0)
            continue;
        printf(" %d, ", x);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

---

Another example is parsing a sentence. Note the two `for` loops can't have initializers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(void)
{
    char buf[1000];
    char token[1000];
    char *src;
    int stop;
    char *dst;

    printf("Enter sentence: ");
    fflush(stdout);

    fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin);

    src = strchr(buf,'\n');
    if (src != NULL)
        *src = 0;

    src = buf;

    while (1) {
        // find non-blank
        for (;  *src != 0;  ++src) {
            if (*src != ' ')
                break;
        }
        if (*src == 0)
            break;

        switch (*src) {
        case '"':  // handle quoted string
        case '\'':
            stop = *src;
            ++src;
            break;

        default:  // handle token
            stop = ' ';
            break;
        }

        dst = token;

        for (;  *src != 0;  ++src, ++dst) {
            if (*src == stop)
                break;
            *dst = *src;
        }

        *dst = 0;

        printf("token: '%s'\n",token);

        if (*src == 0)
            break;

        ++src;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've never seen a for loop with the first part empty before, what does that imply?

Comment: I've updated my answer to [try to] explain how the `for` loop works. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your input to `y` is wrong:

```
scanf(" %d", y);
```

should be

```
scanf(" %d", &y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
scanf(" %d", &y);
```

instead of:

```
scanf(" %d", y)
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `scanf(" %d", y);` you should have `scanf("%d", &y);` (space removed in scanf, unless you want to scan for space+your_number)